# How to aggregate ORs from the same study, and after that use these aggregated effect sizes to do a meta-analysis in R

Tags: r, aggregate, random-effects, meta-analysis

I am trying to do a meta-analysis with a random effects model. The data includes: study, Odds Ratio (OR), and 95% confidence interval. For the meta-analysis, some categories were made consisting from several variables. For example, the variable substance use disorder includes alcohol use disorder, marijuana use disorder etc. Because of these categories, some studies have several effect sizes on the same variable.

To adjust for same study, I want to aggregate the effect sizes of each study before using these effect sizes in the meta-analysis random effects model.

```
dput(data)
structure(list(author = c("Study 1", "Study 1", 
"Study 2", "Study 3", "Study 3", 
"Study 4", "Study 5", "Study 5"
), OR = c(2.88, 0.75, 1.09, 4.24, 2.64, 2.77, 2.6, 3.2), ci.low = c(1.07, 
0.31, 0.39, 0.89, 1.25, 1.63, 1.2, 1.6), ci.high = c(13.38, 1.81, 
3.03, 20.25, 5.62, 4.69, 5.7, 6.2), row.names = 4:8, class = "data.frame")
```

Using `metagen` with `cluster = author` did not seem to adjust correctly, as the results of the random effects model did not differ before or after using  `cluster = author`.

```
metagen(TE = OR, lower = ci.low, upper = ci.high, 
        studlab = author, fixed = F, random = T, cluster = author,
        sm = "OR", data = data)
```

How can I correctly aggregate the effect sizes of one study into one aggregated effect size, and use this in a random effects model to get a pooled OR?

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data we can use (not `str(..)`, please use `dput(..)` or similarly unambiguous and easily consumed format) and relevant code.

Comment: What does “did not seem to adjust correctly” mean specifically? Error? Erroneous results?

Comment: @Mike I've added a piece of code of the `metagen` function

Comment: @r2evans I've added sample data

Comment: @jpsmith  the results of the random effects model did not differ before or after using `cluster = author`